# What's the use of the .eh_frame section in C programs?

Tags: c, static-linking

I have a statically linked executable compiled from a C program. `objdump -x a.out` indicates the presence of the `.eh_frame` section, even after `strip -s`. **Why is this section useful in a C** (non-C++) program? **What are the risks** of stripping it (with `strip -R .eh_frame`)?

Comment: The other question is indeed similar, but it doesn't address the question I raise: Why is the .eh_frame section useful in C? Please reconsider your vote for duplicate.

Comment: Agreed, this question is not at all a duplicate of the linked one. I was just about to ask the same thing myself. The linked question is about how the `eh_frame` section works, but for C++ programs. This question is about what it does for C programs, where stack unwinding is not part of the language.

Comment: You need to know a platform...

Comment: Related: [Why GCC compiled C program needs .eh_frame section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300819/why-gcc-compiled-c-program-needs-eh-frame-section)

Comment: Does this answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300819/why-gcc-compiled-c-program-needs-eh-frame-section#answer-26302715

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From remyabel's comment and OP's confirmation, the answer to the OP question is available via another SO question as linked by:

[Why GCC compiled C program needs .eh_frame section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300819/why-gcc-compiled-c-program-needs-eh-frame-section#answer-26302715)