# How do I perform a relocatable link, discarding unused functions without breaking .eh_frame

Tags: c++, gcc, ld

I'm compiling some code using -ffunction-sections so each function is in its own section and can be discarded if it's not used.

Then I discard unused functions by generating a new relocatable object during the link stage by using -r and --gc-sections.

However, when I finally link the resulting object into an executable, the linker reports:

"ld: myobject.o(.eh_frame+0x7f0): reloc against `*UND*': error 2"

I think this is because a symbol was discarded but it remains referenced by .eh_frame. I noticed that the error can also sometimes be reported with a section name instead of "*UND*" where the section name is the name of an undefined symbol that used to refer to the section before it was removed but I don't know why there are two different ways this turns up.

How can I work around this (eg, maybe remove .eh_frame entries containing only unresolvable relocations)?

Comment: I suspect this is specific to something in your setup (OS/toolchain, compiler and/or linker command line options, etc.) since it's unlikely that *everyone* using `-ffunction-sections` and `-gc-sections` is having this problem - if they were, it would already be reported and fixed.

Comment: It seems to be caused by using --gc-sections with -r. Then the final link suffers this problem.

Comment: Why are you using `-r`?

Comment: I suspect you've found a real bug, but since `-r` is rarely used/obscure, that's probably why nobody has noticed.

Comment: I'm using -r because I want to produce two sets of functions/data sections: those used via one set of entrypoints and thus form a kernel, and those used via a second set of entrypoints and thus form a bootstrap module. By using -r I can create a .o file for each of those two and then my final link can put their sections into two different areas in memory. I might have an alternative that doesn't use -r but I have to solve lots of other problems using that approach.

Comment: Updated the question to include the fact that this is an object that has had sections removed during a relocatable link.

Comment: Offhand I think you should wait to use `--gc-sections` until the final link (i.e. omit it at the `-r` link). I don't see how `--gc-sections` could work, even conceptually, with `-r` since there are no roots for the GC; *everything* should get collected.

Comment: --undefined=symbol prevents the section containing "symbol" from bein collected.I put several of those arguments into a file used with @ to specify them on the commandline. anyway, I've gone back to looking at ways to do two full links and incorporate the sections of one into the other in order to perform the same job.

Comment: Although... Perhaps --print-gc-sections can be used when linking an object file which is itself discarded, and simply using the list of gc'd sections to decide which sections to include in which ELF segments and which to /DISCARD/ in the *real* link. That should be reasonably straightforward.