# How to remove a specific ELF section, without stripping other symbols?

Tags: gcc, elf, objcopy

I have an ELF 32-bit x86 file which contains an `.eh_frame` section, despite my attempts<sup>1</sup> to remove it.

I'd like to remove the `.eh_frame` section, without touching any symbols in other sections, including unused ones.

`strip` does not seem to have an option `--remove-only`, and it always ends up modifying other sections.

How can I remove a single ELF section without modifying anything else in the file?

<sup>1</sup>As suggested in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300819/why-gcc-compiled-c-program-needs-eh-frame-section), I tried several variants of `gcc-3.4.3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-exceptions -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-unwind-tables`, but the `.eh_frame` section is always there. This is probably due to the fact that I have to use an old GCC (3.4.3)... the source file itself contains nothing special that might require these sections: `int main() { return 0; }`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`strip`, despite the name, is not the right tool here.

A possible solution is `objcopy --remove-section .eh_frame a.out`, where `a.out` is the name of the ELF file to be modified.

Unfortunately, unless you know about `objcopy`, you may end up searching for solutions with `strip`, without finding any.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like objcopy doesn't shrink the binary after removing a section, i.e. everything after the space used by removed section is not moved (and references updated) to close the gap.