# How does glibc backtrace() determine which stack memory are the return addresses?

Tags: x86, arm, stack, glibc, backtrace

As far as a program is concerned, a stack is just a bunch of memory. How does the backtrace function determine which stack bytes are instruction pointer return addresses as opposed to which are just function arguments, etc?

Comment: Presumably using `.eh_frame` stack-unwind metadata to allow unwinding even without a frame pointer; hopefully that gives you something to google on.

Comment: @Peter I don't think backtrace() is that smart, I believe it only works for traditional frame pointer layouts.

Comment: Seems like I am wrong about, seems like it goes the use the [unwind capability from libgcc](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/debug/backtrace.c.html#68) which means the eh_frame stuff when supported. @PeterCordes

Comment: Related: [Why GCC compiled C program needs .eh\_frame section?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26302715)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as a program is concerned, a stack is just a bunch of memory.

That is correct. If you knew *nothing* about the structure of the program, you wouldn't be able to unwind its stack.

The easiest structure to use for unwinding is one where a single "frame pointer" register is reserved to always point to the current frame, and the frame contains *previous* frame pointer at a known offset.

That is the mechanism that was used for a long time on `i*86`, and is still used on many RISC machines. It makes stack unwinding easy and very fast, but it is not efficient on register-starved machines, such as `i*x86` and to lower extent `x86_64`, because that frame register can be put to better use elsewhere.

The solution is to create augmentation data, which describes *how* to find the current frame given current set of registers and memory contents (e.g. "current frame is at offset NN from `$rsp`", or "at offset MM from `$rbp`", "previous frame is at offset J from current frame", etc.)

That is effectively what `.eh_frame` is. Remove it from your binary, and no stack unwinding will be possible.

This mechanism is also significantly slower than a simple frame pointer walk, requires complicated code, and is error-prone (compilers are not guaranteed to emit correct unwind descriptors, and hand-coded assembly may not have them at all).

There are [other solutions](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ShadowCallStack.html) which make unwinding fast and easy, but they require a different calling convention.